# what is the price of firebase scheduled functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm using scheduled functions in firebase, example:

```
exports.pushDataEveryMinute = functions.pubsub.schedule('21 16 13 04 02')
.onRun((context)=> { 
  database.ref("metadata/lastUpdate/").set("OFF"); 
  return null; 
});
```

So this is a scheduled function, so what is the meaning of a job and task, because I have a 3 free jobs per month, and I'm afraid to pay if I use for example 4 scheduled functions.

Answer (score 1):

With this amount of invocation and so simple function I am sure you will not pay at all for one more invocation.

If you take a look on [Firebase pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) there is free quota per month. So you will got ex 2 millions of free invocation per month.

I guess that this example function is much simpler, but still if it's not something extremely complicated you still should not exceed free quotas.

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much. So at first I was afraid for using these functions, and when i write a function, and when i deploy it, i delet it, and this is the biggest mistake, because i guess when i delet and i write it again , my first free attempt is gone, and i have just three free jobs in a month, so the best way is to modify the scheduled function, and deploy it again.